# Update Mongo document if new data comes

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I fetch a collection of categories from a website and add them into MongoDB.

But as this collection comes from a third party so what I want is if the third party updates the categories list it should update my mongo collection.

How to update the particular document on basis of regionId assuming regionId's are fixed and they form basis of serach in mongo.

I want to achieve this in mongo that updates i.e inserts that particular element in the document and if no new data comes then the document should remain the same

**ORIGINAL**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa38b33ff7a19a11ef11d3e"), 
    "regionId" : NumberInt(3526), 
    "regionName" : "So Cal", 
    "categories" : [
        "Other", 
        "Topicals", 
        "Tincture", 
        "Cannabis", 
        "Edibles", 
        "Extracts", 
        "Prerolled", 
        "Vape Cartridges"
    ]
}
```

Assume I get new element category ***Seeds***   in  regionId 3526 I want to add it to the same document 
**UPDATDED**

```
{ 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aa38b33ff7a19a11ef11d3e"), 
        "regionId" : NumberInt(3526), 
        "regionName" : "So Cal", 
        "categories" : [
            "Seeds",
            "Other", 
            "Topicals", 
            "Tincture", 
            "Cannabis", 
            "Edibles", 
            "Extracts", 
            "Prerolled", 
            "Vape Cartridges"
        ]
    }
```

**CODE**

```
   function fetchPresentCategoryInMongo(n, resultObj, callback){
    db.collection(dbConfig.COLLECTION_NAME).update(
        {"region_id": parseInt(resultObj.categoryObj.regionId)}, 
        { $addToSet : { 'categories' : resultObj.categoryObj.categories }},{ upsert: true },
     function (error, query_result) {
        console.log(error, query_result.result, "======find ===================");
        if (error) {
            return callback(error, null);
        }
        else {
            return callback(null, query_result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is your question, are you encountering any errors in your code?

Comment: I am not able to achieve the desired output it is making a new document if some new element comes in the category , I want if some new element comes in categories it should be added otherwise document should remain the same
@chridam

Comment: It's because you have the `{ upsert: true }` option which performs an upsert operation i.e. update if found or insert new document otherwise. Remove that if the behaviour is not desired since `$addToSet` will not duplicate the array element being added if it already exists.

Comment: but what if no entry is there in mongo corresponding to that region id in that case I want it to create new document @chridam